# Pseudo-element variants with tailwindcss-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

With the introduction of The JIT engine on TailwindCSS, it's possible to use [pseudo-element variants](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#pseudo-element-variants) like `::first-letter` [as in this example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/5YnDsZ0BOs).

[As for this issue](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/94), I understand `tailwindcss-rails` version 2+ uses JIT.
I'm using the gem version 2.0.30, but `<p class="first-letter:text-red-400">Lorem Ipsum</p>` is rendered all in black.

Am I missing something here?

My `tailwind.config.js` looks like

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you added it on the <head> tag of your view layout? Something like this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'tailwind', 'data-turbo-track': 'reload' %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JIT** was introduced in 2.1 not 2.0.

Quote: *"Tailwind CSS v2.1 introduces a new just-in-time compiler for Tailwind CSS that generates your styles on-demand as you author your templates instead of generating everything in advance at initial build time."*
Source: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Looks like you need to upgrade just a bit more to the version **2.1** :)

---

EDIT: looks like the problem is with using `span` tags.

In the comment under my answer you posted a code snippet that works and the one that doesnt. On that basis i have this example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/C2CrUdKCd0
in which you can see that if you use `p` tags - everything works, but when you use `span` it does not work.

Hope this helps resolve the issue :)

Comment: I use `tailwindcss-rails 2.0.30`, which uses `TailwindCSS 3.3.3` (https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/releases/tag/v2.0.30). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: hmm.. then it is weird - i just used your code snippet in my project and it worked for me: the L was red.  its hard to answer your question because i cant see how your system is configured.

Comment: I understand. After creating the Rails 7 app (with importmaps) I haven't changed anything related to TailwindCSS.

Comment: other styles are working correctly? maybe there is some issues in loading order of the styles itself in the layout file and they are overriding some of tailwind features? maybe there are other gems that might conflict with JIT? also you can try to create absolutely new rails app to create a working example, and then step by step add all the features you have in your main project. when snippet stops working again you will be able to find the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually works `<td class="hidden px-3 py-4 first-letter:capitalize text-sm sm:table-cell"><%= violation.violable.name %></td>` while `<div class="inline-block mr-3"><span class="inline-block h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-300"></span><span class="first-letter:capitalize">yet to start</span></div>` doesn't.

Comment: i have updated my answer based on your code snippet :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the take and look into that.